# Getting a method from a super class through an instance

Tags: java, inheritance

Suppose there is a class A, B and C and an interface BImpl.

In A we create an instance of B through BImpl:

```
class A {

    BImpl bimpl;

    A() {
       bimpl = new B(); 
    }

    public void speak() {
        bimpl.getLanguage();
    }
}
```

In B we have a method getWords() that it overrides from the BImpl interface. This method calls retrieveLanguageDict() from it's super class.

```
class B extends C implements BImpl {

    @Override
    public void getWords() {
        retrieveLanguageDict();
    }
}

interface BImpl {
    void getWords();
}

class C {

    protected void retrieveLanguageDict() {

    }
}
```

My question is: if I needed to, how would I call the method retrieveLanguageDict() from class A?

Comment: Declare the field of type `B`, so that the method declaration is visible for that type. Not every `BImpl` must have the method you're looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method is protected. It can only be called by the class itself, its subclasses, and other classes in the same package.

On top of that, class A is working through an interface BImpl. The only methods accessible via the reference `bimpl` are those declared in the Bimpl interface.

You could solve the issue by making `retrieveLanguageDict()` a member of the interface, and by changing its access control to `public`.

That said, you might also consider whether `retrieveLanguageDict()` is an implementation detail of some implementers of BImpl. If so, it would be better *not* to call it from outside the implementations of BImpl.